# Should I worry about Flutter and Dart version being different?

Tags: flutter, dart, version

Flutter uses the `dart-lang` SDK (and executable). So when I want to see what version I'm using, I run this and get the following:

#### Flutter

```sh
flutter --version
```

**Output**

```
Flutter 1.23.0-18.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 198df796aa (7 days ago) • 2020-10-15 12:04:33 -0700
Engine • revision 1d12d82d9c
Tools • Dart 2.11.0 (build 2.11.0-213.1.beta)
```

Version: `2.11.0`

#### Dart

But when I check my machine's `dart` version. I see something different..

```sh
dart --version
```

**Output**

```
Dart SDK version: 2.10.2 (stable) (Tue Oct 13 15:50:27 2020 +0200) on "macos_x64"
```

Version: `2.10.2`

---

How can I make sure I'm always using the same `dart-sdk` and executable between the `dart` tool and `flutter`? What is managing the two tools? Should I worry about Flutter and Dart version being different (*edit*)?

Comment: Your title and body are asking different questions. Are you asking whether you should worry, or how to make them the same?

Comment: Did you install the dart sdk separately from flutter?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I updates my body to include the header question. Honest, mistake on my part - thanks for catching it. But I don't recall installing them separately, unfortunately. I may have though. I'd image one would use the other or something of that sort?

Comment: No flutter uses the dart sdk that is downloaded with flutter even if you already downloaded it separately. I did not install dart separately from flutter and my dart version changes with the flutter channel I'm on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter version and dart version don't have to be the same. You can see from [here](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk), the latest Dart SDK version is 2.10.0. But there are lots of newer versions in Flutter as in [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows). Dart has a version note in their documentation:

> As of Flutter 1.21, the Flutter SDK includes the full Dart SDK. This site’s documentation and examples use version 2.10.0 of the Dart SDK.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed the dart sdk separately before, you could just delete it, and then the dart sdk included in the Flutter will be used automatically.

find the installation folder `which dart`

if it is not in the flutter SDK folder

then just `rm -r` the folder

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't worry, but more importantly, the 2 versions are **built for each other.**

For example, when you install an old version of Flutter, the version of Dart which will be used will **not be the latest** version of Dart, but the one that was released around the same time as the Flutter you are using.

I learnt this in my question/ GitHub issue, [Choose specific Dart version used by Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97640#issuecomment-1027845288)
.

> **Flutter is tightly coupled to Dart**, so you can't mix and match versions. If you really wanted to run a specific version of Dart that it wasn't built with you would need to fork the framework and the engine and **custom-build your own combination**, which would almost certainly include lots of changes to make them compatible. [Stuart Morgan, Flutter team](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97640#issuecomment-1027830974)